# Display loader only when api call will be longer then 1 sec

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, angular-observable

I have tried and I still trying to create a mechanism in Angular using rx that will display my loader, but only if the API call is longer than 1 second, if it is shorter I would not like to display it.

I've tried many different ways, but I haven't been able to achieve what I need.

The closest I came to a solution was in this case:

```
        const apiCall = this.searchService
            .query(this.query)
            .pipe(finalize(()=> this.loading = false));

        timer(1000)
            .pipe(takeUntil(apiCall))
            .subscribe(()=> {
                this.loading = true;
            })

        apiCall.subscribe(result => {
            //do smth
        })
```

In this case loader would be shown after the API request was completed, but it would immediately disappear becouse of finalize method (and it would also be called twice).

Does anyone have an idea on how to do something like this because I'm running out of ideas?

Comment: maybe an animation could work for that? Initial size of loading indicator would be 0,0... after 1 second delay it get's it's width/height.  (problem is if it takes 1.1 seconds you'd still have the sort of blinking in and out behavior I think you're trying to avoid)

Comment: Agree with @pcalkins, this kind of stuff is better handled with transitions. You can't predict how much it will take the call, so at any point you decide to blink in the loading spinner it could happen that in the next 100ms the call finishes. Just set the state to loading = true immediately, but make the spinner fade-in during 300ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested your code but my guess is your code will call the api twice and thats the reason it removes the loader on the first call and second call doesn't care about the loader at all. something like this should work.

```
const apiObservable = this.searchService.
  .query(this.query).pipe(startWith(null));

const isLoadingObservable = timer(1000).pipe(
  map(() => true),
  startWith(false),
  take(2),
);

combineLatest(apiObservable, isLoadingObservable).pipe(
     tap(([resp, isLoading]) => this.isLoading = isLoading),
     filter(([resp, isLoading]) => resp !== null)
).subscribe(resp => {
  this.isLoading = false;
  //do smth
});
```